# анимация с использованием таймингом видео в HTML 5, CSS 3, JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

есть некоторое видео, без разницы какое, мне нужна анимация, что бы при скролинге страницы покадрово шло видео. Образно 100px проскролил 10 кадров проигралось. Есть такой пример на сайте [sonos.com](https://www.sonos.com/en/shop/roam.html). [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

на вот этом моменте. Это именно видео. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const playbackConst = 500;
const height = document.getElementById("height");
const video = document.getElementById('video');

video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {
  height.style.height = Math.floor(video.duration) * playbackConst + "px";
});

function scroll() {
  const frameNumber = window.pageYOffset / playbackConst;
  video.currentTime = frameNumber;
  window.requestAnimationFrame(scroll);
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(scroll);
```

```css
#video {
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<video id="video" autoplay="" playsinline="" muted="" preload="auto">
  <source src="https://assets.sonos.com/im/default/images/products/roam/roam-exploded-view-black.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<div id="height"></div>
```

Comment: А можно как то сделать что бы анимация работала плавнее?!

Comment: Это не анимация, это видео. Чтобы видео было более плавным надо увеличить fps. Вот визуальное сравнение разных значений fps https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pfiHFqnPLZ4